# 未投稿ですが、この質問・回答は可能ですか

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)を真似て、プログラミング導入のための手引をWikiとして作成したいのですが、以下の内容で可能ですか

---

タイトル
C言語を学習したい人の書籍ロードマップ

---

質問欄
この質問はプログラミングに興味があってC/C++言語でプログラムを書きたい入門者に多い質問です。
勉強のロードマップとして活用できるように回答はWiki形式で行います。

英語の書籍の場合は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)を参照してください。

---

回答(フォーラWiki)

C入門

環境が見当たらずインストールに不安がある場合
やさしいC 第4版
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/479737098X

世界でいちばん簡単なC言語のe本―C言語の基本と考え方がわかる本
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798028843

かんたんC言語 (プログラミングの教科書)
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4774142328

C初級
以下、環境はインストールにいついては触れない

全くCに触れたことがない場合
新版 明解C言語 入門編
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4797327928

標準ライブラリまで網羅したい場合
独習C 第4版
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798115770

入門の時点でポインタについて詳しいしい説明が必要な場合
苦しんで覚えるC言語
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798030147

C中級、C++初級

コードの書き方に不安を覚えている場合
C実践プログラミング 第3版
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4900900648

文字列の扱いに慣れたい場合
新版 明解C言語　中級編
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4797350040

ポインタをマスターしたい場合
C言語ポインタ完全制覇
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4774111422

ソースファイルを分割できるようになりたい場合
新版 明解C言語 実践編
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4797329955

規格に沿った学習がしたい場合
プログラミング言語C 第2版 ANSI規格準拠
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4320026926

C++への入門がしたい場合
ロベールのC++入門講座
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4839926050

独習C++ 第4版
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798119768

C上級、C++中級

その他の言語を呼び出したい場合
C言語教科書(上達編) 誰でもわかる! C言語ベテラン技
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4822284212

協調性のあるコードを書きたい場合
リーダブルコード ―より良いコードを書くためのシンプルで実践的なテクニック (Theory in practice)
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4873115655

より高度なテクニック、ノウハウを得たい場合
Effective C++ 第3版 (ADDISON-WESLEY PROFESSIONAL COMPUTI)
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4621066099

STLの利用法をマスターしたい場合
STL標準講座―標準テンプレートライブラリを利用したC++プログラミング (Programmer’s SELECTION)
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4881357786

STLよりも一歩踏み込んだライブラリが使用したい場合
Boost C++ Librariesプログラミング
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798017043

C++上級
（どのような書籍が良いのか思いつきませんが、オープンソースのライブラリの利用やUnity関連書籍でもいいのか考えています。）

C入門、C初級から１冊、
C中級、C++初級は苦手克服として１～３冊、
C上級、C++中級、C++上級から時間と予算、目的に合わせてと考えています。

未分類

並び順、目的については購入者レビューと目次から得られた情報からどのように有効か考えたものです。
目的は、その人その人が抱えている問題への処方と考えているので他の書籍よりどの点が優れているかを重視して表記しています。
入手困難・絶版のものは平等に入手可能でないので記載できませんでした。
良い本なのに無い、目的が達成されない、他の目的の方が大きい、内容が重複し過ぎている、良い書籍ではない、もっと説明を加えたい場合、wikiは100の信用度が有れば自由に変更可能です。
それ以外の方は信用度50以上の方はコメントに50以下の方は返信いただけ有用と判断される場合記載可能です。

---

タグ
[プログラミング入門][よくある質問][c][c++][wiki]

Comment: 英語版のSOでは、このような情報を[タグwiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info)に入れているケースがあります。質問にするより、タグに入れたら更新もできるし、情報が一箇所にまとめることもできます。どう思いますか？

Comment: 一応、タグ内のWikiに投稿しましたが、回答のWikiがどのようなときに使われるのか、ぱっとしません。

Comment: @natsukitinyak C言語のタグとC++言語のタグに投稿して頂きましたが、同じ情報を両方に載せるとメンテナンスが困難ですので、C言語のみで良いでしょうか？両方に載せる場合にはC言語に特化したものとC++言語に特化したものに分けた方が良いかなと思うんですが。

Comment: 全く同じ情報ではなくC側は少し削ったんです。C++がCベースに開発されたために内包されるイメージがあるので、[辞典類ではCとC++をセットにして書いているもの](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798025968)もあるんです。[C,C++,C#は非常に似た側面がある](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2757072.html)ので参考にできる書籍が重複していたり網羅するために順をおっている必要があったりするのです

Comment: @natsukitinyak そうですか。ではC++の方も書籍情報を載せたいと思います。

Comment: @natsukitinyak もはやさらにオフトピック話題ですが、原則としてC言語とC++言語は全く異なる言語です。C++はCから派生したので雰囲気が似ている、と捉えた方がその実態に近いです。とはいえご指摘のように、市中書籍では混同されて扱われることも多いのも事実ですから、両タグwiki内容はこれからコミュニティによって更新されていけばよいと思います。